# Do any languages have verbal inflection with a plural object?

Tags: verbs, grammar, inflection, grammatical-number, grammatical-object

The verb in a language like English can inflect for person, for example:

*I see the cat* > *he sees the cat*

and the verb can inflect for tense:

*I see the cat* > *I saw the cat*

But do any languages inflect for the singular/plural aspect of the object?
i.e. is there a language where the verb 'to see' would be different in the two contexts 'I see the cat' and `I see the cats'

Comment: Note that many languages do this with past participles, like French *je les ai vu(e)s*. // And does agglutination count as inflexion?

Comment: Velupillai 2012 mentions that "those of us mostly used to Western European languages might assume that verbal affixes only say anything about the 'subject', the A argument in transitive clauses. **However, it is actually much more common to mark both the A and P of transitive clauses on the verb**" (p. 249; emphasis mine - Alex B.). See Siewierska 2011 for further details http://wals.info/chapter/102

Comment: @AlexB, thanks for the link. The fact that Spanish is in the "Both A&P" group, but French in the "Only A" group makes me suspect that the definitions are quite fuzzy.

Comment: @dainichi, the link I posted is on A-P verb agreement in person only. As far as I know, there is no person agreement between the verb and direct object in Modern French.

Comment: @AlexB., and there isn't in Spanish either. But I suspect they're putting Spanish in the A&P group because the object pronouns are sometimes written together with the verb, as in decirlo ((to) say it) dilo (say it!) etc. But French has that to some extent as well (dis-moi), so the distinction seems rather arbitrary.

Comment: @Cerberus Also Italian: "Le ho viste/li ho visti". :)

Comment: @Alenanno: Si! Io lo so.

Comment: @Cerberus, but not in Spanish. Los he visto, Las he visto.

Comment: @dainichi, take a look at http://gsil.sc-ling.org/pubs/franco.html

Comment: @AlexB., interesting, thanks for the link (although I haven't bought the article). Yes, I kinda assumed something like this was part of what the classification was based on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

Biblical Hebrew has object suffixes which distinguish the person, gender and number of the object. Example (from the Shema:)

> ושננתם (veshinantam) "and you shall chew them over",

('ve-shinan-ta-m': "and shall-chew-over you them")

Georgian has a set of prefixes and suffixes which combine to show the person and number of the subject and object For example:

> ხედავ (khedav) "you see it";
>   მხედავ (mkhedav) "you see me";
>   გვხედავ (gvkhedav) "you see us".

Comment: Likewise, [Swahili](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_(linguistics)#Swahili), typically for Bantu languages, has verbs marked for agreement with subject and direct object in number and gender (where "gender" refers to Noun Classes, not sex). And of course any number of languages allow cliticized objects both singular and plural, like _je t'aime, je vous aime_, etc.

Comment: I am not sure the Hebrew here is the best example of what the OP is asking.  It can easily be perceived simply as a contraction of the verb and the object pronoun.  Maybe this is an unimportant distinction, but just as I would not consider "sic'm" (sic him/them) or "get'r done" (get her done) to be marking the gender and number of the object of the verb, I am a little reluctant to accept veshinantam as doing so.  I am open to discussion and changing my mind, however. :)

Comment: I agree that these suffixes are reduced forms of the pronouns; but it is generally reckoned that all personal inflections probably have their origin in bound pronouns.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to read your question strictly as "Are there languages that agree with their objects only with respect to plurality?" There are some cool examples of this. For instance, Classical Nahuatl usually has full agreement with both object and subject for both person and number. In ditansitive verbs, though, we cannot have full agreement with all three arguments. Instead, the verb agrees for number and person with the subject and indirect object and there is a suffix -im, which agrees with plural animate direct objects.

Xi-nech-**im**-maca huehuexolo.

2Ssg-1Osg-PL-give **turkey**

"Give me **some turkeys**."

If *huehuexolo* were singular or inanimate, **-im** would not appear. See *The Syntax of Agreement and Concord* by Mark Baker for more on this kind of phenomenon, which he calls two-and-a-half agreement because you can agree with two arguments and part of a third.

WARNING: The Nahuatl is missing some crucial diacritics that I do not know how to represent on the web.

Comment: Try finding and pasting the missing diacritics from pages like these by Alan Wood: [a](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/basic_latin.html) [b](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/latin_1_supplement.html) [c](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/latin_extended_a.html) [d](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/latin_extended_b.html) [e](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/ipa_extensions.html) [f](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/latin-extended-c.html) [g](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/latin-extended-d.html) [h](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/latin_extended_additional.html)

Answer (score 1):

Like Nahuatl, Dakota verbs agree with both the subject and object of a sentence (sometimes the indirect object, if it is animate and the direct object is not)

**Hokṡída kiƞ mázaska wa-k’ú.**                "I gave the boy money"

*boy   det   money 1Ssg.give*

**Hokṡída kiƞ mázaska wic̣á-wa-k’u**               "I gave the boys money"

*boy   det   money 3Oanim-pl.1Ssg.give*

**mázaska ma-yá-k’u**          "You gave me money"

*money  1Osg.2Ssg.give*